# Grepl first letters, two patterns to match

Tags: r, grepl

I have the following data frame. I want to create a column called A1B1 with a 1 if there are strings starting with A1 or B1 or both in the data frame and a zero if not.

What am I doing wrong here:

```
set.seed(1)
Data <- data.frame(id = seq(1, 10), 
Diag1 = sample(c("A123", "B123", "C123"), 10, replace = TRUE), 
Diag2 = sample(c("D123", "E123", "F123"), 10, replace = TRUE), 
Diag3 = sample(c("G123", "H123", "I123"), 10, replace = TRUE), 
Diag4 = sample(c("A123", "B123", "C123"), 10, replace = TRUE), 
Diag5 = sample(c("J123", "K123", "L123"), 10, replace = TRUE), 
Diag6 = sample(c("M123", "N123", "O123"), 10, replace = TRUE), 
Diag7 = sample(c("P123", "Q123", "R123"), 10, replace = TRUE))

A1orB1 <- c("^A1", "^B1")

Data$A1B1 <- apply(Data[-1],1,function(x)as.integer(sum(grepl(paste(A1orB1,collapse="|"), x))==1))
```

I would expect to have a one with ID's (1,2,3,4,5,8,9,10) but I have only ones in 4,5 and 9.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At present you are computing the *sum* of the number of `A1...` or `B1...` strings and comparing it to 1.

Perhaps replace `sum()` with `any()` (and consider breaking your code up into a few more intermediate chunks to make it more readable ...). Or you could just replace `==1` with `>=1` in your code.

```
ss <- paste(A1orB1,collapse="|")
ff <- function(x) as.integer(any(grepl(ss,x)))
Data$A1B1 <- apply(Data[-1],1,ff)
```